# Difference in Chrome's rem calculation between font-size and line-height on Mac vs. Windows?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, web

I put together a very basic pen to demonstrate what's going on here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZjbmWE

[And a screencap for those of you who don't have a Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSecL.png)

Basically, what I'm trying to do is use rems for sizing throughout my web app, but I noticed an inconsistency in sizing between Mac and Windows, even though I was viewing the app in Chrome on both platforms.

What I'm seeing is that when setting `html { font-size: 50%; }`, the computed font size on Mac ends up being 9px, not 8px as I would expect (given the default browser size is 16px). This wouldn't be a problem, except Chrome is apparently still using 8px as the basis for calculating rem-based font-sizes, while still using 9px to calculated rem-based line-heights, as we can see in the pen.

If you inspect the `<span>` in the pen and look at the computed styles (with Chrome on Mac), you'll notice that the font-size is 16px (8 * 2), but the line-height is 18px (9 * 2). So we have two different interpretations of what a rem means going on between font-size and line-height.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: This seems like a rounding issue (just guessing), because if I change your example from `html {
  font-size: 50%;
}` to `html {
  font-size: 8px;
}`, the line-height and font-size match.

Comment: Also, testing with `200%`, `75%`, and `125%`, the line-height and font-size match. But if I try with `25%`, `font-size` computes to `9px`, while `line-height` computes to `18px`. So I think it must be some issue with setting the `font-size` to a percentage lower than `50%`. Like it won't allow the line-height to go below `18px` via percentage. Weird.

Comment: Yup, they still match at `56.25%` but start drifting (line-height holds at 18px) when html is set to `56.2%`.

Comment: Filed a bug : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=863662