# Percentage font sizes (CSS)

Tags: html, css, font-size, percentage

I currently have the following html snippet:

```css
#first {
  font-size: 100%
}

#second {
  font-size: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p id="first">This is the first sentence</p>
  <p id="second">This is the second sentence</p>
</body>
```

Because % refers to the percentage of the container (in this case body) I would expect the font size to be 16px for #first and 8px for #second.

However, when I inspect the computed values in my developer tools in Chrome I see that #first has a font size of 16px, but #second has a font size of 9px.

Am I missing something here? Would be great if someone could explain what's happening.

[image]

Comment: In Edge, computed font-size shows 16px and 8px.

Comment: On my Windows 10 laptop Edge/Chrome and Firefox all show 8px as expected. What systems are you using (operating system, device, browser version)?

Comment: Chrome: Version 92.0.4515.107 (Official Build) (x86_64)
Device: Macbook Pro, 2019
OS: macOS Catalina, Version 10.15.7

Comment: Added a screenshot as well

Comment: I also have 8px in Chrome on Windows. On Android it's also 8px.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51334585/difference-in-chromes-rem-calculation-between-font-size-and-line-height-on-mac

Comment: Check that your browser doesn't have a minimum font-size configured.